# Secure way of running OpenVPN in windows 7

Tags: vpn, windows-7

Is there a more secure way of running OpenVPN GUI in windows 7?

Currently we have to use the *runas* command and savecred. This is fairly insecure as it allows the user to run any application as admin.

Has anybody found a workaround for this? Or maybe another free VPN client you would recommend?

Comment: What have you done to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the OpenVPN service which installs with the rest of the OpenVPN client package, you can autostart some connection to an OpenVPN server named, say, 'work'. This happens as part of the regular Windows servicing stuff, so there is no need for 'Run as' commands (which is the best you get in Windows I believe).

This way, you can deploy keys and certificates to the client machines without having to make them user readable. As long as the service user can read them, you are fine. I restrict access to the sensitive identity bearing files to a specific Windows user. Along with a suitable group policy, this makes up a reasonably hardened solution.

I have OpenVPN clients running this way and it works fine. Basically, users will be connected to the OpenVPN server as soon as they are connected to some network that provides access to the OpenVPN server.

The OpenVPN GUI application does not appear to control the OpenVPN service, unfortunately - it does its own thing. So the service solution only works if you're OK with clients being 'always on' so to speak.

Hope it helps!